# How to create php soap wsdl client with wsHTTPBinding?

Tags: php, ssl, wsdl, soap-client, wshttpbinding

I am trying to make a php client from a wsdl, that consumes a WCF service. 
I have managed to consume the web service with a C# console application by only passing the credentials(no pem certification needed).

The url for the wsdl is the following(it is a test environment):

```
https://extenavigator.ukho.gov.uk/serviceB2B/submitUKHOOrdering.svc?wsdl
```

**So If someone wants to try to create a soap client use this wsdl.**

"Attempting to access with an account that is lacking the relevant service permission will result in a response with a ProcessResult.Failure Acknowledgement and a Message added to the Messages property of: The service [serviceName] is not available to the user [userId]" (from the provider).

So a working soap client with wrong credentials should return the above message.

In order to create a soap client in php first I created the stub classes via wsdl2phpgenerator. Then I instantiate the soap client as below:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 480);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 400);

$orderServiceClient = new OrderingService(array('login' => DIST_B2B_USERNAME, 'password' => DIST_B2B_PASSWORD, "trace"=>1, 
"exceptions"=>1, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'keep_alive' => false, 
"connection_timeout" => 240, 'verifypeer' => false, 'verifyhost' => false, "ssl_method" => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS));
```

where OrderingService is the stub class that extends SOAP client class.

At last I call a method like this:

```
$getHoldingsRequest = new GetHoldingRequest(DIST_ID, 25555, ProductType::AVCSCharts); // set some params for the called method

$responce = $orderServiceClient->GetHoldings($getHoldingsRequest); // call the method
```

The error I get is: Error Fetching http headers

I have enabled ssl in php.ini and in the apache conf file. I am using a windows PC.

I have read this posts:

[Connecting to WS-Security protected Web Service with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953639/connecting-to-ws-security-protected-web-service-with-php)

[SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824799/soapfault-exception-http-error-fetching-http-headers)

I figure out that the problem is that the soap header must be customized in order to pass the credentials ("Username and Password authentication over SSL")

I have also tried to create custom soap headers:

```
 class WsseAuthHeader extends SoapHeader 
{
    private $wss_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd';
    function __construct($user, $pass, $ns = null) 
    {    
    if ($ns) 
    {        
        $this->wss_ns = $ns;    
    }    

    $auth = new stdClass();    

    $auth->Username = new SoapVar($user, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);     
    $auth->Password = new SoapVar($pass, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);    
    $username_token = new stdClass();    
    $username_token->UsernameToken = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns);     
    $security_sv = new SoapVar(        
                            new SoapVar($username_token, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns),        
                            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'Security', $this->wss_ns);    

    parent::__construct($this->wss_ns, 'Security', $security_sv, true);
    }
}
```

and

```
 $wsse_header = new WsseAuthHeader("xxxx", "xxxx");

 $orderServiceClient = new OrderingService(array('trace' => true, 'exceptions' => true, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY, 
'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'keep_alive' => false, 'connection_timeout' => 240));

 $orderServiceClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($wsse_header));
```

Finally

```
$getHoldingsRequest = new GetHoldingRequest(DIST_ID, 25555, ProductType::AVCSCharts);
 $getHoldingsRequest->setRequestId($GUID);

try {
$responce = $orderServiceClient->GetHoldings($getHoldingsRequest);

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}


 echo "<pre>" . var_export($orderServiceClient->__getLastRequest(), TRUE) . "</pre>";
```

I get:

Error Fetching http headers

NULL

I have also tried other things mentioned in the above posts with no result.

From the posts mentioned above:

"But as I said above: I think that much more knowledge about the WS-Security specification and the given service architecture is needed to get this working."

**So if someone has experience with soap client and is able to create a php client for this wsdl that would be a great help.**

For GUID I used the following function:

```
  function getGUID(){
if (function_exists('com_create_guid')){
    return com_create_guid();
}else{
    mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
    $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
    $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
    $uuid = chr(123)// "{"
        .substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
        .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
        .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
        .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
        .substr($charid,20,12)
        .chr(125);// "}"
    return $uuid;
   }
}

   $GUID = getGUID();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new and not sure my post will be helpful or not but I will try to help you - If you have already got your WSDL file or URL then

-you can use php SoapClient

- kindly ignore ,if post is not matching your requirement

Try to follow example give below and also your WSDL file structure(holding 
function and parameter via XML)

**Its up to you, can put step 1 and step 2 code inside class/function, or can use in simple given way.**

**Step 1-**

try 
{

$client = new SoapClient(SOAP_CLIENT_WSDL_URL, array('soap_version' => SOAP_VERSION, 'trace' => true));
        return $client;

} catch (SoapFault $fault) {

trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);

die();

}

**Step 2-**

result =  $client->your_wsdl_containing_function("follow_wsdl_parameter")

$xml_last_response = $client->__getLastResponse();

echo '';print_r($xml_last_response);

Comment: Can you be more detailed about step 2? Do I have to combine step1 and step 2?

Comment: you can put step 1 code inside initialize_soap_client(), then in step 2 you can see it is called,and then object soapclient can be used to call function which is inside wsdl, atlast you will receive your final response/xml,then convert xml response into array

Comment: Now already updated answer, there is no initialize_soap_clie‌​nt() , you can use it in a simple way, also suggest you to see you request_response also before last_response for debugging

Comment: I edited the question. In case you(or someone else) wants to try to consume the mentioned service.